# Minimal terminal editor alternative to vi and nano

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, usability

What terminal/console mode alternatives to `vi/vim` and `nano` are available? I am looking for minimal, good looking and friendly text mode editor for complete newbies with PC.

I remember I've seen somewhere a terminal editor that showed menu on <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of cryptic (and somewhat ugly) ^X shortcuts an the bottom, but searching through GitHub I couldn't find it.

**UPDATE**: It appeared that "friendly for complete newbies" requires more explanation. Let's take a common scenario when user tries to use `vim` for the first time (which is often set as a default editor). When `vim` runs with text to edit, there is no help displayed and typing produces strange results, so users hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> and it "doesn't work". A friendly editor, **for example**, would show help on <kbd>F1</kbd> key, contain menu system with highlighted shortcuts, provide syntax highlighting out of the box, and do that all by default.

Comment: @karel, is it able to run *in* terminal?

Comment: I have not noticed the updated to this question before. You have introduced changes to question that markedly depart from the original request. Please roll back the edit and file a new question with the request for an editor with a menu accessible with <kbd>F1</kbd>. Please read carefully [this discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14012/is-it-acceptable-to-change-the-title-and-the-actual-meaning-of-a-questions-afte) at the Meta site.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa F1 is just one usabilty feature to be friendly for newbies and better editor may have many others.

Comment: I once again invite you to post your additional requirement as a new question. Please respect the web site conduct.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa ok, let me clarify the question for you.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa done, please take a look.

Comment: I am proposing this question for closure since the user is not willing to follow the conduct [ascertained at Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14012/is-it-acceptable-to-change-the-title-and-the-actual-meaning-of-a-questions-afte).

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I don't see the OP changing the question, I see them clarifying what they originally meant.

Answer (score 20):

**[micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/)** shows help on <kbd>F1</kbd>, implements syntax highlighting, exits on <kbd>Esc</kbd>. No menus, but supports plugins.

Comment: how big is this compared to nano or pico? looking for something that will be used rarely from within a container...and so would like the smallest fooprint possible

Answer (score 8):

My best guess is, you're searching for [the **ne** (the nice) editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_(text_editor)).

Shows an ncurses Menu when pressing ESC twice or F1 once. Pretty straight forward menu. Save, Save as... Quit etc.

```
sudo apt install ne ne-doc
```

Comment: So much time suffering with Vim Nano Etc... what a great little app (thumbsup)

Answer (score 7):

## [Joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/)

Back in the 1990s many of my colleagues preferred [**Joe**](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/) to either `vi`, `pico` or `emacs`. It is still considered by some as the most user friendly terminal based text editor.

> JOE is a full featured terminal-based screen editor which is
>   distributed under the GNU General Public License (GPL). JOE has been
>   around since 1988 and comes standard with many Linux distributions.
>
> [image]

Joe is not installed by default but is available from the **universe** repository:

`sudo apt-get install joe`

## [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

[image]

While far from the minimalistic approach you request, Emacs is highly customisable. So, with a bit of work you can get it to behave in the most suitable way for you.

Useful resources :

- [Emacs Mini Manual (PART 3) - CUSTOMIZING AND EXTENDING EMACS](https://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor3.html)
- [Emacs Begineer's HOWTO: Customizing Emacs](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Emacs-Beginner-HOWTO-4.html)

It is also available from the official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

To run it in the terminal you must use the `-nw` flag. If you intend to use it regularly you may create an alias.

```
emacs -nw
```

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. I think the biggest problem with both `vim` and `emacs` is that people keep pushing it regardless of if it fits the story or not. =) Joe looks good - small, doesn't require knowledge to be run in text mode, but its user interface is on par with `nano`. Let me edit the question to narrow the search scope.

Comment: Forget the above comment - it is informative. In both Joe and Emacs I don't see `F1` key visible on the screen. Does it work at all?

Answer (score 2):

Can I also suggest 'jed' console editor, a bit like 'ne' in some respects with menus (accessible via F10), simpler overall (less fully-featured) and with a bit of colour.

```
sudo apt install jed
```

[image: Jed Editor]

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Ash:
https://akashnag.github.io/ash/

It is a minimal text editor for the terminal with common key bindings and is very easy to use; also quite good looking